# Boost interprocess message_queue has non const get_num_msg(). Why?

Tags: c++, message-queue, boost-interprocess

In boost 1.53 the message_queue_t has this member function:

```
size_type get_num_msg();
```

This returns the number of messages currently stored. Never throws. I don't see any reason why this can't be const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a bug, and it has been fixed in boost revision #83470.